# Identifying two different threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning multithreading in java.My doubt is,is there any way two identify two different threads if they have same name below is my code

```
package com.rajeev.test2;

    public class Test11 extends Thread {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
            new Test11().start();
            new Test12();
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Thread.currentThread().setName("ram");
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
        }
    }
    class Test12 extends Thread{

        static{
            new Test12().start();
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Thread.currentThread().setName("ram");
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
        }
    }
```

### output

```
Thread[main,5,main]
Thread[ram,5,main]
Thread[ram,5,main]
```

I know they are two different threads having same name,so how to know they are different thread without changing name ?

Comment: [`getId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getId()) can also be useful !

Comment: Like @NINCOMPOOP says - Two threads can have the same *name* but their `ThreadIds` will be different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can track the `Threads` having same name by their `ID` which will be unique.

Every thread has a name for identification purposes. More than one thread may have the same name. If a name is not specified when a thread is created, a new name is generated for it.

The `JVM` tracks threads by their `ID`, not by their name.

```
long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
```

Comment: Beware: [“*When a thread is terminated, this thread ID may be reused.*”](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getId()) when looking at a console output.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the name of the thread in order to identify a unique thread. The `Thread` class has a `getId()` method that returns a `long` number generated when the thread was created, and that is unique to the thread. Use this in order to know if they are different.

Answer (score 0):

**Using getId method**

Use getId to identify the uniqueness of the Thread.

Thread id is to be set while creating a new thread. Irrespective of the constructor which will be used.

`Thread() 
Thread(Runnable, String)
Thread(Runnable)
Thread(String)
Thread(ThreadGroup, Runnable, String, long)
Thread(ThreadGroup, Runnable, String)
Thread(ThreadGroup, Runnable)
Thread(ThreadGroup, String)`

all the constructors used init method. In this method has thread id generation.

Also In clone method also has thread id generation.

If Thread gets cloned , new thread id set for new thread reference.

**Using equals & Hashcode method**

Another way to identify thread uniqueness is using equals and hashcode.

Thread doesnt has same equals and hascode method.

So using hashcode to differentiate thread uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply compare the two objects of Test11 and Test12(i.e the threads) using equals operator.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code is completely weird.

- Never subclass `Thread` - there are very rare cases in which this is necessary.
- Usually a `Thread` gets its name from the code that creates it. This makes it easy to give every new thread another distinct name. Do not set the name in the `run` method.
- Please don't start threads in the `static` constructor of a class.

Probably your example should look simliar to that:

```
public class ThreadExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
        new Thread(new PrintThreadNameTask(), "thread-1").start();
        new Thread(new PrintThreadNameTask(), "thread-2").start();
    }
}

class PrintThreadNameTask implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
    }
}
```